# $.getJSON render data not working in IE8 but working in IE9 & FireFox

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8, render

I am making this function call below to get the results based on the drop down selection made by the user and render the results within a Div tag. The problem is this works fine in Firefox and IE9 but does not show the results table in IE8. I am able to see the alert message with retrieved values in IE8 but the table shows empty. Any help is appreciated.

```
function retrieveExams() {
    $.getJSON('/request/opscert/retrieveOpscertExams',
            { certificateType : $('#selectedApplicationType').val(),
                classTypeOne : $('#selectedApplicationClassTypeOne').val(),
                classTypeTwo : $('#selectedApplicationClassTypeTwo').val()},
            function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                var html = $('#OpsCertExams').render(data);
                alert(html);
                $('#examTable').html(html);
                $('#examTable tr:odd').css('background-color','#BBBBAA');

                $('#ajaxWaitNoteDiv').hide();
            }
    );
}
```

//This is the table below embedded within a div tag to display the results. This table
works fine and shows the results in Firefox and IE9.

```
<table id="examTable" style="width:100%"></table>
```

//This is the script which iterates and displays the results

```
<script id = "OpsCertExams" type="text/x-jsrender">
    <tr>
        <td style="width:20%;font-size:12px;text-align:center">{{:examDate}}</td>
        <td style="width:20%;font-size:12px;text-align:center">{{:examTime}}</td>
        <td style="width:20%;font-size:12px;text-align:center">{{:examLocation}}/td>
        <td style="width:20%;font-size:12px;text-align:center">{{:examType}}</td>
    </tr>
</script>
```

Comment: I tried several options from solutions towards similar problems here and it does not seem to work in this siuation. Any suggestions/help....